# VSTS Build not generating code coverage details - .Net core 2.1

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using VSTS build pipline to build my project `( ASP .Net Core 2.1 )` .
I have added `test` command to run test project and enabled `Publish test results and code coverage` checkbox to be able to view code coverage results.

[image]

I can see the test results are getting uploaded but can't see any information regarding code coverage.

[image]

Am I missing anything ?

**UPDATE 1**
I am using `Hosted VS2017` Agent Pool

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS - how to get Code Coverage results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982938/vsts-how-to-get-code-coverage-results)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk , I have gone through that post but it looks like that post belongs to .Net framework 4.6 framework, I am having issue with .Net core 2.1 and I am 100% sure that I have enabled code coverage in my task.

Comment: Do you use hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have updated original question.  I am using 'Hosted VS 2017' Agent Pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code coverage can be collected by adding --collect "Code coverage" option to the command line arguments. This is currently only available on the Windows platform.

In your case your arguments should look like *--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"*

This information is available if you hover your mouse over the (!) icon besides the checkbox for "Publish test results and code coverage"