# Not able to render Code Coverage HTML results in the "Code Coverage" tab in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a classic build pipeline in Azure DevOps that builds and run tests for a .Net Core 3.1 app.
I am using self-hosted build agents running Windows Server 2019 OS

**Below is the pipeline screenshot**
[image]

**My tasks:**

1. Restore Nuget
2. Build the solution in release mode
3. Install latest vstest.console.exe tool
4. Run tests using above tool and generate .coverage file
5. Install CodeCoverage.exe from Nuget
6. PowerShell script to convert .coverage to .xml
7. Using ReportGenerator task to generate HTML and Cobertura (HTMLInline;HTMLChart;Cobertura)
8. Publish the code coverage results to the server using Cobertura.xml from step 7 and also uploading HTML report folder

**Publish Code Coverage Task**
[image]
The HTML report directory is generated by ReportGenerator task.

**Build runs successfully**
Publish Code Coverage task log
[image]

**Build run summary**

[image]

**Published files by the build**

[image]

**Code Coverage tab**

[image]

**Issue: The code coverage tab does not display the HTML reports**

Comment: Hi @Prado, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: This issue is still open. What I understand from the responses below is that if we use "Visual Studio Test" task in the build then that somehow prevents uploading HTML reports later in the pipeline. This is not confirmed yet. I am waiting for someone to provide more concrete response. I am not looking for "Coverlet" option here.

Comment: Could you try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738732/13903626) and then kindly share the result here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662921/code-coverage-report-display-blank.html) on Azure devops. Now, we could only download the report, and open it with Visual Studio.

Azure devops only support the download link for .coverage files currently. The white page you see is a UI glitch. This scenario is only supposed to render a download link to the coverage file.

Besides, this issue has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here: [support vstest .coverage "code coverage" build results tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366142/support-vstest-coverage-code-coverage-build-result.html)

This feature request is On Roadmap, I believe it will be released soon, you can follow this thread to know its latest feedback.

In addition, I found a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627918/view-code-coverage-report-on-azure-devops-portal) and I have tested via the answer, set the code coverage tool to Cobertura, then I get the code coverage report in the Azure DevOps pipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies with step 4.

```
4. Run tests using above tool and generate .coverage file
```

If a `.coverage` file is created and left alone, Azure DevOps will pick it up and use it over anything else you create later. So basically your `coverage.xml` or any generated HTML report is ignored at the Code Coverage tab.

So instead of using VSTest task and whatever you used beneath that, try adding a .Net Core Test to your pipeline and configure it to spit out "XPlat Code Coverage" using coverlet collector. Make sure NOT TO pass in any `.runsettings` file via `--settings`. Before doing any of that, you will need to add the NuGet `coverlet.collector` for all your test projects.

[image]

Then add your task to publish the coverage results. You don't need the report generator, it's now built-in.

[image]

That's all. Hopefully, you will be able to see the generated HTML getting rendered under Code Coverage tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you settings so I will share mine which works

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added screenshot of my Publish code coverage task